# jQuery: Nested hover and click function to show and hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a project, I need the following:

- If you hover the first part of the text, the second part of the text should be visible. *(Works so far.)*
- If you unhover the first part of the text, the second part of the
  text should be hidden. *(Works so far.)*
- If you click the first part of the text, the second part of the text should be visible, and should be still visible after unhovering. *(Doesn't work.)*
- If you click the first part of the text again, it should be like
  before, with a hover-sensitive state. *(Doesn't work.)*

Here is my try:

```js
// Works generally

$("div").mouseover(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");
});


// Doesn't work

$("div").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
});

$("p:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

I would be very, very thankful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```js
$("div").mouseover(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("hover");
});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("hover");
});

$("p:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.hover {
  display: block !important;
}

.clicked {
  display: block !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the element (first part of the text), you should add a class like "locked" so when you hover out of the element you check that first (and not make it `display: none` if that's the case, otherwise you're setting `display: none` anyways, on mouseout.

Also, the description says you should "unlock" it when you click in the `first` part again, not the `second` one, if you do

```
$("p:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");
});
```

You are doing it when clicking in the `second` part instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you! I understand what you mean, but when I tried it like that, I failed. Could you please show me how you would code it?

Comment: sure, let me try it and post it here!

Comment: oh, check @cbrxyz's answer! that's exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this is what you want.

```js
// Works generally
var trackMouseClickDivTag = false;

$("div").mouseover(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
  if(trackMouseClickDivTag == false) 
    $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");
  else 
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
});


$("div").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "block");
  trackMouseClickDivTag = (trackMouseClickDivTag == false) ? true : false;
});

$("p:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
  $("p:nth-child(2)").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```